# Order does not exist, for the Shipment process to complete

Tags: event-observer, invoice, shipment

I am trying to create an Observer to automatically create and email shipment to the customer whenever a new invoice is created.

I am having trouble created the shipment as the I keep getting an exception when I try to create an invoice.

I am Observer the `sales_order_invoice_register` register event.

Here's my code:

```
public function salesOrderInvoiceShipmentCreate($observer)
{

    $orderIncrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
    Mage::log($order,Zend_Log::INFO,'order.log',true);

    if (!$order->getId()) {
        Mage::throwException("Order does not exist, for the Shipment process to complete");
    }

    if ($order->canShip()) {
        try {
            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
                ->prepareShipment($this->_getItemQtys($order));

            $shipmentCarrierCode = '';
            $shipmentCarrierTitle = '';

            $arrTracking = array(
                'carrier_code' => isset($shipmentCarrierCode) ? $shipmentCarrierCode : $order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode(),
                'title' => isset($shipmentCarrierTitle) ? $shipmentCarrierTitle : $order->getShippingCarrier()->getConfigData('title'),
            );

            $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($arrTracking);
            $shipment->addTrack($track);

            // Register Shipment
            $shipment->register();

            // Save the Shipment
            $this->_saveShipment($shipment, $order, $customerEmailComments);

            // Finally, Save the Order
            $this->_saveOrder($order);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}

protected function _getItemQtys(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    $qty = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $_eachItem) {
        if ($_eachItem->getParentItemId()) {
            $qty[$_eachItem->getParentItemId()] = $_eachItem->getQtyOrdered();
        } else {
            $qty[$_eachItem->getId()] = $_eachItem->getQtyOrdered();
        }
    }

    return $qty;
}
```

The exception is being thrown on but I can't figure out why??

Any help would be appreciated please...

Comment: please add the event name that you are observing to the question

Comment: @programmer_rkt Thanks for you input, please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LastRealOrderId` value on the `checkout\session` object is cleared when the order is saved.  See:  `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()`

The order is already available from the $observer object that is passed for that event, see: `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_invoice::register()`  where the event is being generated.

Try:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

In your function instead of the LastRealOrderId